# Extract int part of a BigDecimal?

Tags: java

In Java, I'm working with the `BigDecimal` class and part of my code requires me to extract the int part from it. `BigDecimal` does not appear to have any built in methods to help me get the number before the decimal point of a `BigDecimal`.

For example:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("23452.4523434");
```

I want to extract the `23452` from the number represented above. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Do you want the entire non-fractional part or literally whatever fits in an `int`?

Comment: Could you explain the difference? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: *"BigDecimal does not appear to have any built in methods to help me get the number before the decimal point of a BigDecimal"*: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValue() ...

Comment: A BigDecimal could have a value much larger than what fits in an `int`, so depending on whether you care about that case or not, you may have to convert to a BigInteger instead or not. Either way there's a simple built-in function to do it.

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t use [toBigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toBigInteger--)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bd.toBigInteger()`

See the docs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toBigInteger()

Answer (score 18):

Depends on what you mean by "extract". What is the type of the result of the extraction? Another `BigDecimal`, a `BigInteger`, an `int`, a `long`, a `String`, or something else?

Here's code for them all:

```
BigDecimal result1 = bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN);
BigInteger result2 = bd.toBigInteger();
int        result3 = bd.intValue(); // Overflow may occur
long       result4 = bd.longValue(); // Overflow may occur
String     result5 = bd.toBigInteger().toString();
String     result6 = bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).toString();

NumberFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0");
fmt.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
String     result7 = fmt.format(bd);
```

---

Explanation of roundings:

- [`RoundingMode.DOWN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN) - Rounding mode to **round towards zero**. Never increments the digit prior to a **discarded fraction** (i.e., **truncates**). Note that this rounding mode never increases the magnitude of the calculated value.
- [`toBigInteger()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toBigInteger--) - Converts this `BigDecimal` to a `BigInteger`. This conversion is analogous to the *narrowing primitive conversion* from `double` to `long` as defined in [section 5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) of *The Java™ Language Specification*: **any fractional part** of this `BigDecimal` **will be discarded**. Note that this conversion can lose information about the precision of the `BigDecimal` value.
- [`intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValue--) / [`longValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#longValue--) - Converts this `BigDecimal` to an `int` / `long`. This conversion is analogous to the *narrowing primitive conversion* from `double` to `int` / `long` as defined in section [5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) of *The Java™ Language Specification*: **any fractional part** of this `BigDecimal` **will be discarded**, and if the resulting "`BigInteger`" is too big to fit in an `int`, only the low-order 32 / 64 bits are returned.

As can be seen from the descriptions, all 4 discards fractional part, i.e. rounds towards zero, aka truncates the value.

Comment: Upvoted as extremely useful and the complete range was a nice touch.  What would be useful is an explanation of the rounding.  I'm guessing result1 rounds down to the nearest whole number, but int and long conversions are less clear.